# Using a Converter to select DataTemplate and maintain binding?

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, binding, converters

I am having trouble maintaining bindings after using a Converter to select which DataTemplate to use for my control.

My control binds to a collection of IAppointment, some being type WorkOrderAppointment some DowntimeAppointment.  I would like to define a tooltip based on the type.  The converter is selecting the correct DataTemplate based on the type, but the bindings within WorkOrderToolTipTemplate and DowntimeToolTipTemplate are not working, as if they do not have a datacontext.

Can someone help me understand whats going on, or even maybe a solution?

Abbreviated XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkOrderToolTipTemplate">
        <Grid
            Name="WorkOrderToolTips"
            Width="400"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="270*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Tooltip Labels -->
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="Site Name:"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="Description:"
                />

            <!-- Tooltip Values -->
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding Appointment.CalendarItem.SiteName}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                />

            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding Appointment.CalendarItem.Description}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                />

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DowntimeToolTipTemplate">
        <Grid
            Name="DowntimeToolTips"
            Width="400"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="270*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Tooltip Labels -->
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="Site Name:"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="Event Classification:"
                />

            <!-- Tooltip Values -->
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding Appointment.Downtime.PlantName}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Text="{Binding Appointment.Downtime.EventClassification}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <converters:ToolTipSelectorConverter x:Key="local_ToolTipSelectorConverter"
        DowntimeDataTemplate="{StaticResource DowntimeToolTipTemplate}" 
        WorkOrderDataTemplate="{StaticResource WorkOrderToolTipTemplate}" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock
        Style="{Binding Appointment, Converter={StaticResource local_AppointmentTextStyleConverter}}"
        Text="{Binding Appointment.Subject}"
        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        >
        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip ContentTemplate="{Binding Appointment, Converter={StaticResource local_ToolTipSelectorConverter}}" />
        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>


<UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard problem with the `ToolTip`, which isn't part of the visual or logical tree, and so doesn't inherit the `DataContext`.

The standard solution is to bind the `DataContext` of the `ToolTip` to the `DataContext` of the `PlacementTarget`:

```
<ToolTip 
   ContentTemplate="{Binding Appointment, Converter={StaticResource local_ToolTipSelectorConverter}}"
   DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately i'm using silverlight and cannot use `x:Static`.

Comment: How about the `RelativeSource` markup extension? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: That seemed to just break the binding for the tooltip.  The converter is no longer firing.

Comment: Try setting the `DataContext` binding on the `Grid` within the `DataTemplate`, using `{RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}` as the source.

Comment: The grid inside of WorkOrderToolTipTemplate now looks like `<Grid Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}" >` but it still does not work.  This DataTemplate is never being selected because the Converter `local_ToolTipSelectorConverter` is never firing.

Comment: It should be `DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"` on the `Grid`, with no `DataContext` on the `ToolTip`.

Comment: I have done this, the Converter is now firing again, but the binding is still not working.  I hookup a converter one of the textblocks in the datatemplat and set a breakpoint.  It is never being hit.